# High IO% with optimal Execution Plan

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've got a package `PKG_P2K_IMP_RESGATE_AUT` that runs a query that has low cost in the Execution Plan, but an enormous IO% time on the AWR.

```
-------------------------------------
SELECT COUNT (1) FROM MAG_V_CXA_LANCTO L, MAG_V_MOV_PEDIDO P WHERE 
L.CODFIL = P.CODFIL AND L.NUMPED = P.NUMPEDVEN AND L.TIPOPED = 
P.TIPOPED AND P.NUMPEDPRINC = :B2 AND P.CODFIL = :B1 AND L.FORMA IN 
(1,2,3)

Plan hash value: 1651369101

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                              | Name                       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                       |                            |       |       |    23 (100)|          |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE                        |                            |     1 |   178 |            |          |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                            |     1 |   178 |    23   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                        |                            |     1 |   147 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                       |                            |     1 |   143 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                      |                            |     1 |   137 |    17   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                     |                            |     1 |   129 |    16   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                    |                            |     1 |   115 |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                   |                            |     1 |   107 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                  |                            |     1 |   103 |    13   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER           |                            |     1 |    85 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |            NESTED LOOPS                |                            |     1 |    72 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 12 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CXA_LANCTO                 |     1 |    48 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 13 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CXA_LANCTO_IDX_PDV         |     1 |       |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| MOV_PEDIDO                 |     1 |    24 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | MOV_PEDIDO_PK_R            |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | MOV_PEDIDO_FINANC_COMPL_PK |     2 |    26 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | MOV_PEDIDO                 |     1 |    18 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | MOV_PEDIDO_PK_R            |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 19 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | CAD_TPNOTA_PK              |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)|          |
|* 20 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN              | CAD_CONDPG_PK              |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | MOV_PEDIDO_COMPL_PK        |     1 |    14 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                | CAD_CONDPG_PK              |     1 |     8 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | CAD_CLIENTE_PK             |     1 |     6 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 24 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | CXA_EVENTO_PK              |     1 |     4 |     0   (0)|          |
|* 25 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | CXA_LANCTO_COMPL           |     1 |    31 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 26 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | CXA_LANCTO_COMPL_IDX02     |     6 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$A3800E45
  12 - SEL$A3800E45 / LAN@SEL$2
  13 - SEL$A3800E45 / LAN@SEL$2
  14 - SEL$A3800E45 / B@SEL$9
  15 - SEL$A3800E45 / B@SEL$9
  16 - SEL$A3800E45 / F@SEL$9
  17 - SEL$A3800E45 / PEDIDO@SEL$67
  18 - SEL$A3800E45 / PEDIDO@SEL$67
  19 - SEL$A3800E45 / TPNOTA@SEL$67
  20 - SEL$A3800E45 / D@SEL$9
  21 - SEL$A3800E45 / C@SEL$9
  22 - SEL$A3800E45 / CONDPG@SEL$2
  23 - SEL$A3800E45 / CLI@SEL$2
  24 - SEL$A3800E45 / EVE@SEL$2
  25 - SEL$A3800E45 / LANCPL@SEL$2
  26 - SEL$A3800E45 / LANCPL@SEL$2

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  12 - filter(("LAN"."CONDPGTO" IS NOT NULL AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION("LAN"."FORMA")))
  13 - access("LAN"."CODFIL"=:B1)
  14 - filter(("B"."NUMPEDPRINC"=:B2 AND "B"."CONDPGTO" IS NOT NULL))
  15 - access("B"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "LAN"."TIPOPED"="B"."TIPOPED" AND "LAN"."NUMPED"="B"."NUMPEDVEN")
  16 - access("F"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "B"."NUMPEDVEN"="F"."NUMPEDVEN" AND "B"."TIPOPED"="F"."TIPOPED")
  18 - access("PEDIDO"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "PEDIDO"."TIPOPED"="B"."TIPOPED" AND 
              "PEDIDO"."NUMPEDVEN"="B"."NUMPEDVEN")
  19 - access("PEDIDO"."TPNOTA"="TPNOTA"."TPNOTA")
  20 - access("D"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "D"."CONDPGTO"="B"."CONDPGTO")
  21 - access("C"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "C"."TIPOPED"="B"."TIPOPED" AND "C"."NUMPEDVEN"="B"."NUMPEDVEN")
  22 - access("CONDPG"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "LAN"."CONDPGTO"="CONDPG"."CONDPGTO")
  23 - access("CLI"."CODCLI"="LAN"."CODCLI")
  24 - access("LAN"."CODEVE"="EVE"."CODEVE")
  25 - filter(("LANCPL"."CODFIL"=:B1 AND "LAN"."TIPOPED"="LANCPL"."TIPOPED" AND 
              "LAN"."TPNOTA"="LANCPL"."TPNOTA" AND "LAN"."NUMPRC"="LANCPL"."NUMPRC" AND "LAN"."NUMLAN"="LANCPL"."NUMLAN" 
              AND "LAN"."DATREF"="LANCPL"."DATREF"))
  26 - access("LAN"."NUMPED"="LANCPL"."NUMPED")

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - (#keys=0) COUNT(*)[22]
   3 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
   4 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
   5 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
   6 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
   7 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22]
   8 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22], "B"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3]
   9 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22], "B"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "PEDIDO"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
  10 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22], "B"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3]
  11 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22], "B"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3]
  12 - "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7], 
       "LAN"."CODEVE"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."CODCLI"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
  13 - "LAN".ROWID[ROWID,10], "LAN"."NUMPED"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], 
       "LAN"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMPRC"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."NUMLAN"[NUMBER,22], "LAN"."DATREF"[DATE,7]
  14 - "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22], "B"."CONDPGTO"[VARCHAR2,3]
  15 - "B".ROWID[ROWID,10], "B"."TIPOPED"[NUMBER,22], "B"."NUMPEDVEN"[NUMBER,22]
  17 - "PEDIDO"."TPNOTA"[NUMBER,22]
  18 - "PEDIDO".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  26 - "LANCPL".ROWID[ROWID,10]
```

```
Elapsed Time (s)   Executions   Elapsed Time per Exec (s)   %Total   %CPU   %IO     SQL Id          SQL Module         SQL Text
20,669.64          108          191.39                      42.12    3.42   93.41   5ufgnmqnyzswp   JDBC Thin Client   call PKG_P2K_IMP_RESGATE_AUT.R...
14,422.03          65           221.88                      29.39    3.28   93.95   4j3bt7f88grgp   JDBC Thin Client   SELECT COUNT (1) FROM MAG_V_CX...
```

The `:B1` is the Branch ID and `:B2` is the Order Number.

I've got an application service that opens up to 100 threads, each one querying for a different order number, and all of a sudden, all of the threads would be stuck in this SQL_ID for 20 minutes, until it gets a timeout.

Today the problem started to happen with less than 10 threads stuck. Just to compare, on the Black Friday we had all the 100 threads executing the package at once, and it didn't get stuck.

When I execute the same query on DBeaver, it would just run in less than 20ms, using the same order number that's stuck on one of the threads.

The expected outcome of the query would be a simple count of just a few lines (0, 1 or 20 at most).

I've already tried clearing the execution plan to force Oracle to build a new one, and he gets this same execution plan.

The problem just happens out of nowhere, and after a couple of hours it just fades away and the package executes in less than a second. It was happening with 20 days of interval, but yesterday we've got it and today it's happening again.

I'm out of ideas of what to do, anyone can help?

Comment: You'll have to check the line 26 in the execution plan. See the `predicate information` for this line. Suspicious is that - contrary to other predicates - here the `CODFIL` is used as *filter* and not as *access*.  This could lead to high number of index access that are thrown away with the filter. Check in a *quick* execution if same index `CXA_LANCTO_COMPL_IDX02` is used. If you have `DBMS_SQLTUNE` run it on the long running SQL_ID, you'll see the hot spot in the document.

Comment: Can you get the [execution plan](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-create-an-execution-plan) (this includes Actual rows and buffers columns) from when it's running slow and post that?

Comment: Are you sure the exec plan you showed is the one from the slow case? When it is running slow, get the SQL_ID and child number and use dbms_xplan.display_cursor to get the actual plan.